# MongoDb: Rename a property in a complex document

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

We have documents saving to MongoDb. The problem is that one of our sub-documents has an `Id` property that is getting returned as `_id`, which is causing serialize/deserialize issues with the C# driver due to how it interprets Id fields (see http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/)

I would like to rename the property from `Id` to `SetId`, but our data is fairly dynamic and simple field rename solutions that I've seen elsewhere do not apply. Here's an example of some heavily edited simple data:

```
{
  "Id": "5a6238dbccf20b38b0db6cf2",
  "Title": "Simple Document",
  "Layout": {
    "Name": "Simple Document Layout",
    "Tabs": [
      {
        "Name": "Tab1",
        "Sections": [
          {
            "Name": "Tab1-Section1",
            "Sets": [
              {
                "Id": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Compare with more complex data:

```
{
  "Id": "5a6238dbccf20b38b0db6abc",
  "Title": "Complex Document",
  "Layout": {
    "Name": "Complex Document Layout",
    "Tabs": [
      {
        "Name": "Tab1",
        "Sections": [
          {
            "Name": "Tab1-Section1",
            "Sets": [
              {
                "Id": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Name": "Tab1-Section2",
            "Sets": [
              {
                "Id": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Tab2",
        "Sections": [
          {
            "Name": "Tab2-Section1",
            "Sets": [
              {
                "Id": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Tab3",
        "Sections": [
          {
            "Name": "Tab3-Section1",
            "Sets": [
              {
                "Id": 1
              },
              {
                "Id": 2
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that the `Set.Id` field can be on multiple tabs on multiple sections with multiple sets. I just don't know how to approach a query to handle renaming data at all these levels.

Comment: You have to use iterate documents and do recursive replace in the code and update the document back to db. I'll use mongo shell with javascript to recursive replace Id.

Answer (score 0):

I took @Veerum's advice and did a manual iteration over the collection with something like this:

```
myCol = db.getCollection('myCol');
myCol.find({ "Layout.Tabs.Sections.Sets._id": {$exists: true} }).forEach(function(note) {
   for(tab = 0; tab != note.Layout.Tabs.length; ++tab) {
       for(section = 0; section != note.Layout.Tabs[tab].Sections.length; ++section) {
           for(set = 0; set != note.Layout.Tabs[tab].Sections[section].Sets.length; ++set) {
                note.Layout.Tabs[tab].Sections[section].Sets[set].SetId = NumberInt(note.Layout.Tabs[tab].Sections[section].Sets[set]._id);
               delete note.Layout.Tabs[tab].Sections[section].Sets[set]._id
           }
       }
   }
   myCol.update({ _id: note._id }, note);
});
```

Perhaps there is a more efficient way, but we are still on Mongo v3.2 and it seems to work well.